# Action Listener opens new window with results

Tags: java

I am learning how to create GUI and need help with understanding actionListeners. Everything is coded but for some reason my Calculate Button is not actually opening up a the new window with the results of the main window. The program is a sandwich shop that allows you to create a sandwich and select a drink. When the user is done they click calculate and it is suppose to open a new window with the sub-total, tax, and final total on it, along with another exit button. Here is all the code I have so far. I would appreciate any guidance that anyone can provide.

**Sandwich Shop**

```
/**
* Creating a menu for a sandwich shop. There are 2 choices for bread, 4 
choices for fixings, and 4 drink selections. The total will be calculated in 
a new 
* window using the actionListener. This new window class is 
CalculateListener. 
* @author Chad Hoye
* @version 1.0
*/

public class SandShop2 extends JFrame  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup_Bread = new ButtonGroup();
private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup_Drink = new ButtonGroup();

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SandShop2 frame = new SandShop2();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public SandShop2() {
    String breadOP;
    String drinkOP = null;
    boolean hamOP = false, turkeyOP = false, cheeseOP = false, mayoOP = false;
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 240, 240);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel bread = new JPanel();
    bread.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    contentPane.add(bread, BorderLayout.WEST);
    bread.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));

    JRadioButton rdbtnWhite = new JRadioButton("White");
    buttonGroup_Bread.add(rdbtnWhite);
    rdbtnWhite.setSelected(true);
    bread.add(rdbtnWhite);

    JRadioButton rdbtnWheat = new JRadioButton("Wheat");
    buttonGroup_Bread.add(rdbtnWheat);
    bread.add(rdbtnWheat);

    if(rdbtnWhite.isSelected()){
        breadOP = "white";
    }else{
        breadOP = "wheat";
    }

    JPanel fixings = new JPanel();
    fixings.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    contentPane.add(fixings, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    fixings.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 0));

    JCheckBox chckbxHam = new JCheckBox("Ham");
    fixings.add(chckbxHam);

    JCheckBox chckbxTurkey = new JCheckBox("Turkey");
    fixings.add(chckbxTurkey);

    JCheckBox chckbxCheese = new JCheckBox("Cheese");
    fixings.add(chckbxCheese);

    JCheckBox chckbxMayo = new JCheckBox("Mayo");
    fixings.add(chckbxMayo);

    if(chckbxHam.isSelected()){
        hamOP = true;
    }
    if(chckbxTurkey.isSelected()){
        turkeyOP = true;
    }
    if(chckbxCheese.isSelected()){
        cheeseOP = true;
    }
    if(chckbxMayo.isSelected()){
        mayoOP = true;
    }

    JPanel drinks = new JPanel();
    drinks.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    contentPane.add(drinks, BorderLayout.EAST);
    drinks.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1, 0, 0));

    JRadioButton rdbtnSoda = new JRadioButton("Soda");
    buttonGroup_Drink.add(rdbtnSoda);
    drinks.add(rdbtnSoda);

    JRadioButton rdbtnBeer = new JRadioButton("Beer");
    buttonGroup_Drink.add(rdbtnBeer);
    drinks.add(rdbtnBeer);

    JRadioButton rdbtnTea = new JRadioButton("Tea");
    buttonGroup_Drink.add(rdbtnTea);
    drinks.add(rdbtnTea);

    JRadioButton rdbtnWater = new JRadioButton("Water");
    buttonGroup_Drink.add(rdbtnWater);
    drinks.add(rdbtnWater);

    if(rdbtnSoda.isSelected()){
        drinkOP = "Soda";
    }else if(rdbtnBeer.isSelected()){
        drinkOP = "Beer";
    }else if(rdbtnTea.isSelected()){
        drinkOP = "Tea";
    }else {
        drinkOP = "Water";
    }

    JPanel Cal_Exit = new JPanel();
    Cal_Exit.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    contentPane.add(Cal_Exit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton btnCalculate = new JButton("Calculate");

    btnCalculate.addActionListener(new CalculateListener(breadOP, drinkOP, hamOP, turkeyOP, cheeseOP, mayoOP));
    Cal_Exit.add(btnCalculate);

    JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");
    btnExit.addActionListener(new ExitListener());
    Cal_Exit.add(btnExit);

    JLabel lblChadsSandwhichShop = new JLabel("Chad's Sandwhich Shop");
    lblChadsSandwhichShop.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    contentPane.add(lblChadsSandwhichShop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
 }
```

**Calculate Listener Class**

```
public class CalculateListener extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private double subtotal;
private double whiteBread, wheatBread;
private double ham, turkey, cheese, mayo;
private double soda, beer, tea, water;

public CalculateListener(String bread, String drink, boolean hamOP, boolean turkeyOP, boolean cheeseOP, boolean mayoOP){
    subtotal = 0;
    whiteBread = 1.00; 
    wheatBread = 1.25;
    ham = 0.75;
    turkey = 0.65;
    cheese = 0.50;
    mayo = 0.25;
    soda = 0.65;
    beer = 3.75;
    tea = 2.25;
    water = 0.0;

    if(bread.equals("white")){
        subtotal += whiteBread;
    }else{
        subtotal += wheatBread;
    }

    if(drink.equals("Soda")){
        subtotal += soda;
    }else if(drink.equals("Beer")){
        subtotal += beer;
    }else if(drink.equals("Tea")){
        subtotal += tea;
    }else if(drink.equals("Water")){
        subtotal += water;
    }

    if(hamOP)
        subtotal += ham;
    if(turkeyOP)
        subtotal += turkey;
    if(cheeseOP)
        subtotal += cheese;
    if(mayoOP)
        subtotal += mayo;

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


    setTitle("Your Bill");
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 0, 0));

    JLabel lblSubtotal = new JLabel(" Subtotal: $" + subtotal);
    panel.add(lblSubtotal);

    JLabel lblTax = new JLabel("Tax: $" + (subtotal * 0.07));
    panel.add(lblTax);

    JLabel lblTotal = new JLabel("Total: $" + ((subtotal * 0.07) + subtotal));
    panel.add(lblTotal);

    JButton btnOk = new JButton("OK");
    contentPane.add(btnOk, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    btnOk.addActionListener(new ExitListener());


}
}
```

**Exit Listener Class**

```
public class ExitListener implements ActionListener {

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
 */
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot a single line: 
`setVisible(true);`

You add it on the bottom of the `actionPerformed(...)` method in the `CalculateListener` class.

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe it was something that simple. I have been debugging this thing for hours trying to figure out why it wouldn't work. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad I could help! I've had lots of silly mistakes like this as well :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are working with different Frames from your main application and your CalculateListener you need to use the listener to calculate the value and set it on your main class where you can update the UI. Try to check the MVC pattern and try to use Java naming standard like without _ on variable names and starting with lower case.